# ASP.NET can't resolve javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How could I run javascript on changing value of `ASPxComboBox`?

I tried this:

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cbx_Organization" runat="server" ValueType="System.String" 
AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="handleOrganizationChange()" Width="230px">
</dx:ASPxComboBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
function handleOrganizationChange() {
    __doPostBack("<%= cbx_Organization.Value %>", "Load_Executives");
}
</script>
```

but `Index.aspx` does not contain a definition for `handleOrganizationChange()`.

Comment: `OnSelectedIndexChanged` is not  for javascript. that is for web forms to request that. You should add a function in your codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using inappropriate syntax. Instead of using OnSelectedIndexChanged attribute try using onchange="javascript:handleOrganizationChange()"attribute and that should work fine..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cbx_Organization" runat="server" ValueType="System.String"  Width="230px"> <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) { handleOrganizationChange(); }" />
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```